# Foreign Key equal Null

Tags: mysql, database, key

I have tabel users:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ePrzychodnia`.`users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `personalId` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `specialization` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `role` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `personalId_UNIQUE` (`personalId` ASC) )
```

and tabel visits. Tabel visits have two foreign key to the users table

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ePrzychodnia`.`visits` (
  `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `doctorId` INT NOT NULL ,
  `patientId` INT NULL,
  `dateVisit` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `hourVisit` DATE NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `doctorId`, `patientId`) ,
  INDEX `fk_visits_Users1_idx` (`doctorId` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_visits_Users2_idx` (`patientId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_visits_Users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`doctorId` )
    REFERENCES `ePrzychodnia`.`users` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_visits_Users2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`patientId` )
    REFERENCES `ePrzychodnia`.`users` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

The second foreign key I set that can be null, because I care about adding an entry to the table visits where it will be empty.
However, when you try to add I get an error

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (eprzychodnia.visits, CONSTRAINT fk_visits_Users2 FOREIGN KEY (patientId) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

What can I do to make the key could be null?

Answer (score 0):

In your relation setup change the action on update and delete

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your foreign key, it's your primary key.  You can't have nullable fields in a primary key.  The id field by itself might be a better choice.

I'm not a fan of nullable foreign keys.  I would add a record to your users table that equates to "not an actual person" and use it as a default.  By the way, the hourvisit field might be redundant.

Comment: I changed my table. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Dana Bruck I do not know if I understand your proposals. But it seems to me that it's something like this:

Table visits

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ePrzychodnia`.`visits` (
  `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `doctorId` INT NOT NULL ,
  `patientId` INT NULL,
  `dateVisit` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `hourVisit` DATE NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `doctorId`, `patientId`))
```

Table without foreign keys. The fields not related to the table users, but I set these fields when I need and this field may be null.

Answer (score -1):

If the id in visits is auto_increment, why you create your PK with 3 columns ??
Just id is enough. You can create a unique index for doctor and patience ID.

Try this model:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ePrzychodnia`.`visits` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`doctorId` INT NOT NULL ,
`patientId` INT NULL,
`dateVisit` DATE NOT NULL ,
`hourVisit` DATE NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `unique_doctor_pacient` (`doctorId`, `patientId`),
INDEX `fk_visits_Users1_idx` (`doctorId` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_visits_Users2_idx` (`patientId` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_visits_Users1`
FOREIGN KEY (`doctorId` )
REFERENCES `ePrzychodnia`.`users` (`id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_visits_Users2`
FOREIGN KEY (`patientId` )
REFERENCES `ePrzychodnia`.`users` (`id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: The unique index on patient and doctor is a bad idea because in real life the patient might really see the same doctor more than once.